# Mapping the value inside a newtype

Tags: haskell, newtype

Assume the following `newtype` is defined:

```
newtype A a = A a
```

And there is a function:

```
f :: A a -> A a
```

Now suppose I define another `newtype`, which contains `A a`:

```
newtype B a = B (A a)
```

And then I'd like to define a function `fb` which operates on `B a` but just uses `f`:

```
fb :: B a -> B a
fb (B x) = B (f x)
```

Now this is quite inconvenient since I have to unwrap and wrap the value inside an element of type `B a`. This won't be that bad if I only had to define one such a `fb` but if there are a lot of them this becomes quite tedious.

I'd be nice if there would be a type-class with a function:

```
(<$$>) :: k a -> k b -> h (k a) -> h (k b)
```

So that `fb` can be rewritten as:

```
fb = (f <$$>)
```

Maybe such an abstraction already exists, but I cannot find it.

Comment: For the special case of newtypes, you should just use `Data.Coerce`, which gives you `coerce :: (a -> a) -> A a -> A a` and `coerce :: (A a -> A a) -> B a -> B a` and `coerce (a -> a) -> B a -> B a`.

Comment: I think [safe coercions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) are the way to go for autowrapping/unwrapping.

Comment: @user2407038, indeed, but that doesn't necessarily have to be at the use site. For a newtype, `instance Functor N where fmap = coerce` is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I don't see how your proposed typeclass would even help. The type `B a -> B a` doesn't unify with `h (k a) -> h (k b)`.

Comment: `<$$>` is reminiscent of `over` from the newtype / newtype-generics package. But `over` requires the external newtype constructor as an additional parameter. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5.1/docs/Control-Newtype.html#v:over

Comment: You're right Daniel. Such typeclass won't help indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use the [newtype-generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5.1/docs/Control-Newtype.html) package, in particular the [`over`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5.1/docs/Control-Newtype.html#v:over) function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Control.Newtype (Newtype, over)
import GHC.Generics

newtype A a = A a

newtype B a = B (A a) deriving (Generic)

instance Newtype (B a)

f :: A a -> A a
f = undefined

fb :: B a -> B a
fb = over B f
```

Notice that `over` requires the outer `B` constructor as a parameter, not only the function `f`.

Comment: I'd be more likely to reach for `Control.Lens.Iso.coerced` along with `Control.Lens.Setter.over`. They don't require `Newtype` or `Generic` instances.

Comment: Actually, you can do it even more simply. See the answer I'm about to write.

Answer (score 3):

If you like danidiaz's answer, you may like this somewhat more "modern" version of `over`:

```
mover :: (Coercible o n, Coercible o' n')
      => (o -> n)
      -> (o' -> n')
      -> (o -> o') -> n -> n'
mover _pack _pack' = coerce
```

This skips all the instances in favor of a bit more explicit passing.

Comment: Nice. Where are `_pack` defined? Also I would expect `mover` to be defined in some library already ...

Comment: Those are just wildcards. You could write `mover _ _ = coerce`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually one of the main reasons to use `newtype` is to derive new Type Class instances for a new type which is wrapped over an existing one.

So its quite simple. You are just expected to write an instance for Functor class and that's it.

```
newtype Team a = Team a deriving (Show , Eq)

instance Functor Team where
  fmap f (Team x) = Team (f x)

newtype League a = League (Team a) deriving (Show , Eq)

instance Functor League where
  fmap f (League x) = League (fmap f x)


upgradeTeam :: (Int -> Int) -> Team [Int] -> Team [Int]
upgradeTeam f = fmap (map f)

upgradeLeague :: (Int -> Int) -> League [Int] -> League [Int]
upgradeLeague f = fmap (map f) 

prependToLeague :: League [Int] -> Int -> League [Int]
prependToLeague x n = fmap (n:) x

*Main> upgradeTeam (+1) (Team [0,1,2,3])
Team [1,2,3,4]

*Main> upgradeLeague (*2) (League (Team [1,2,3,4]))
League (Team [2,4,6,8])

*Main> prependToLeague (League (Team [2,4,6,8])) 42
League (Team [42,2,4,6,8])
```

Comment: This won't work in my case since `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. The function I want to reuse has type `A a -> A b`, hence I need something like `??? :: (A a -> A b) -> B a -> B a`. Note that I'm not operating on elements of type `a` (in your example), but on elements on type `Team a`. For the problem I'm dealing with `A a = Map a Integer` so this example won't work. Function `over` in the other answer seems to fit the bill.

Comment: @Damian Nadales `A a -> A b` is in fact partial application of `fmap g ` on `A` type where `g` is type `(a -> b)` so `:t fmap g` would give you `(f a -> f b)` where `f` represents Functor `A`. Then all you need is to apply another `fmap` but this time on type `B` like `fmap (fmap g)` or ` fmap . fmap $ g` which is in practice what happens in the Functor instance of the `League` type in above code. If you prefer Functor instance of League (your B type) to operate directly on `(A a -> A b)` instead of `(a -> b)` then make the Functor instance of League like `fmap f (League x) = League (f x)`.